# How to remove the selecterow style in a gridview on cancel button - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm using the following code to highlight the selected row in a gridview. I want to remove this style when I click the **cancel** button.

```
<selectedrowstyle backcolor="LightCyan" forecolor="DarkBlue" font-bold="true"/>
```

I have used this code `this.gvArticles.SelectedRow.Style.Clear();` to remove, but it is not working.

Can anyone pls help me out here.

Comment: You will have to reset the selection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this solution

clear selectedindex of gridview by setting it to -1.

```
this.gvArticles.selectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in the case of a gridview with a dataset as a datasource

```
 protected void grdViewDetails_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
            {
                grdViewDetails.EditIndex = -1;
                grdViewDetails.DataSource = YourDatasource; //a dataset in my case

                //Bind data to the GridView control.
                grdViewDetails.DataBind();
            }
```